# JMock - strange syntax for adding expectations

Tags: java, mocking, jmock

I am currently writing a couple of tests involving JMock. I cannot understand the following structure of the code:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {  //context is of type Mockery of course
            {
                allowing(csv).getFileName();
                will(returnValue(fileName));
            }
        });
```

Analysing slowly, as far as I know,

```
context.checking(new Expectations() { ... }
```

This will generate an anonoymous instantiateion of `Expectations`. But why do we have another brackets right after this, and then some strange, static I believe, methods such as allowing() etc? If someone could explain to me from Java point of view what is going on here I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second set of braces form an [instance initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), and its code is copied by the compiler into every constructor for the class. This gives you access to the instance members. In the case of JMock's API, it provides a terse way to initialize the expectations. You could achieve the equivalent thing (though with a warning when compiling `Expectations` itself about an unsafe call to an overridable method from the constructor) with a template method.

```
public abstract class Expectations {
    public Expectations() {
        buildExpectations();
    }

    protected abstract void buildExpectations();

    ...
}
```

And in your test

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {
    protected void buildExpectations() {
        allowing(csv).getFileName();
        will(returnValue(fileName));
    }
});
```

I definitely prefer the shorter version. :)

Answer (score 6):

Instance initializers are interesting. They only place I have really seen them used a lot is with JMock. Consider a simpler more understandable context. You can create a map and add items to it:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(){
    {
        put("One","Something");
        put("Two","Other");
    }
};
```

Maybe this will help you to see what JMock is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Some people believe that creating expectations in static initialisers,  with static methods
provides cool looking , terse, fluent and easily readable syntax  for specifying expectations
- and I agree with them. Awkward syntax is not only cool thing in mocking frameworks - there is lot of cool bytecode manipulation under the hood.

Comment: Not really answering my question I'm afraid